# Python open() function : can't normally print the file after using a for loop

Tags: python

As the title: after using a for loop to print every line of a file, I can't print the file with another for loop.

Does the for loop change the pos variable?

```
pos = open('nnn.txt','r')
print pos
count = 0
for line in pos:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('Hey'):
        print line
        count += 1
print count

count = 0
print line
for lines in pos:
    lines = lines.rstrip()
    print lines
    count += 1
print count
```

[the content of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVgzw.png)

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uZmB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Does] the for loop change the pos variable?

Yes it does. Iterating over a file moves the "pointer" to the end of the file, so you can no longer read from it.

You can reset the pointer to the beginning using `pos.seek(0)`. Then you can read from it again.